# Unity C# On Instantiate gameObject Leap Motion

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

having a minor problem...  I'm doing an Explosion on the particle System and want to drop it in the game Object Prefab(Clone) after that once is collides with my HandController "Leap Motion" and it will be destroy that game Object. How do I implement the coding by using Instantiate?

Answer (score 0):

you'll need to destroy the gameobject the same time as instantiating the explosion, the space shooter tutorial covers this exact situation, check it out

https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/space-shooter-tutorial